# Setting up XDEBUG in my dev environment

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, php

At my company, our PHP file isn't configured to use XDEBUG. This is making me feel like a blind man when trying to fix bugs and I absolutely need the debugger to understand the flow of code. We develop remotely, with our servers set elsewhere. I want to configure the php.ini file to have xdebug but more importantly I want to do this specifically for my development environment. Essentially the php.ini file i intend to alter resides in

```
/etc folder. (needs root access, I have root access)
```

Our dev folder is more like:

```
developer1 developer2 developer3 developer4 developer5 myDevelopmentEnvironment
```

So technically, i want to edit this php.ini file but have the settings changed only for **myDevelopmentEnvironment**, essentially override the main php.ini file in my folder.

Other particulars of interest :

```
  Development machine : Windows
    Server : linux (I putty in)
    Editor: Eclipse (may move to NetBeans)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable XDEBUG from an .htaccess file,

Eg.

```
php_value  zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so
php_flag   xdebug.remote_enable on
php_value  xdebug.remote_port 9000
php_value  xdebug.idekey PHPSTORM-XDEBUG
php_flag   xdebug.remote_connect_back on
```

Comment: the example is using phpstorm

Comment: yes but how does this address my broader concern of not changing the main php.ini file but having it specifically overriden for my dev environment?

Comment: You wouldn't have to touch the php.ini file, as u load the extension in your htaccess.  Another option if you are using separate virtualhosts per developer is to set the ini directory in your virtual host definition with PHPINIDir = /path/to/your/php/ini/dir

Comment: The line `php_value zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so` is incorrect. It should read `php_value zend_extension /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so` which will not work either. You can not load a PHP extension in a `.htaccess` file.